# Android compilation trouble after adding and removing BlackBerry SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry

I installed BB tools for Eclipse, just added and removed BB Nature to one of my projects.
And now, I can't compile it (for Android).

[image]

Eclipse told me about some troubles in AndroidManifest.xml:

**native-code: armeabi AndroidManifest.xml /VitocarsAndroidApp AndroidManifest.xml BlackBerry Verifying Problem**

But the manifest is OK, no one line is highlighted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.asap.vitocarsandroidapp"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.04" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.asap.vitocarsandroidapp.system.VitocarsApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.asap.vitocarsandroidapp.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.asap.vitocarsandroidapp.TableViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_table_view" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.asap.vitocarsandroidapp.PartActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_part" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.asap.vitocarsandroidapp.PhotoViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_photo_view" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.asap.vitocarsandroidapp.UserRegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_register" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.asap.vitocarsandroidapp.ConfirmPhoneActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_confirm_phone" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.asap.vitocarsandroidapp.OfficeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_office" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.asap.vitocarsandroidapp.PriceOfferActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_price_offer" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.asap.vitocarsandroidapp.RegionOrderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_region_order" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.asap.vitocarsandroidapp.MapView"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map_view" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I already spent a lot of time, trying to solve it.

Maybe, somebody can help me?

Comment: I completely uninstalled BlackBerry tools from Eclipse, and now everything is ok. But I think, it is not best way to do it.

Comment: BlackBerry plugin does not get along well with other eclipse plugins. Since eclipse is a portable app, I'd recommend to have a eclipse install only for BlackBerry development with no other plugin installed.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue.

Only uninstalling the Blackberry plugin solved it for me.

I guess that the Blcackberry plugin still left some remainders in the validation process of Eclipse, even though I removed the Blackberry nature from the project.

Answer (score 0):

Check the .project file and remove all the * rim * stuff.

A build command and nature was leftover when i ran into this problem.